# Java: How to redirect the contents of a text file to java file as keyboard input

Tags: java

I have written the following program:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class greeter{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String line = input.readLine();
            System.out.println("Hello, " + line + "! How are you today?");
            line = input.readLine();
            }
        catch (IOException ioex) {
            ioex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I redirect the contents of a text file to this program to be interpreted as keyboard input? Basically, I want it to be able to take the contents of a text file (name.txt) and read it as keyboard input.

My reference material says to use

```
%> java greeter < name.txt
```

but I do not know what this means, or what it is referring to. To be clear, I am not trying to modify my program to read a text file, but input a text file as keyboard input.

Thank you!

Comment: "input a text file as keyboard input" - You need to be more specific.

Comment: Looks like you want to use standard input (stdin). The code seems correct, and the `java greeter < name.txt`  command should be executed in a shell such as `cmd` (`%>` is a shell prompt). I wouldn't use the term "keyboard input" as it makes it sound like you're trying to read keystrokes (e.g. `shift+a` instead of `A`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the code snippet you have provided is in reference to using a unix terminal.

```
%> java greeter < name.txt
```

In the above example you have a java program greeter that takes the input from name.txt.  Similarly if you wanted to create a file from the output of the java program you could do something like this.

```
%> java greeter < name.txt > output.txt
```

Notice the direction of the carrots.. essentially you are pointing stdin and stdout the way you want it to go.  For more on this, reference the following link.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-io-redirections.htm

As for your java question..

You were close except you have to loop on the system.in to get your input.

```
    try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Hello, " + line + "! How are you today?");
        }   
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        ioex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the file setup and calling int via the command line.

```
-MBP:testing$ cat names.txt 
nick
sam
john
-MBP:testing$ java greeter <names.txt 
Hello, nick! How are you today?
Hello, sam! How are you today?
Hello, john! How are you today?
```